# Making a constantly updating Image (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

So i am messing around with making a simple AI and stuff with basic C#, and in this project i have alot of points which i've been visualising by making a bitmap.
This bitmap i have rendered/loaded to an image object in the WPF window.. but my problem is that this is rendered each milisecond, making the framerate quite bad - so how would i make this better?

Can i load it 'constantly'? or should i take another approach?

What i got now is pretty simple but i can show the important parts anyway, taken out of the full class:

```
private static Bitmap BitMap = new Bitmap(500, 500);

static Graphics GraphicFromBitMap
{
    get
    {
        return Graphics.FromImage(BitMap);
    }
}

public static BitmapSource loadBitmapAsImage()
{
    IntPtr intPtr = BitMap.GetHbitmap();
    BitmapSource bitmapSource = null;
    try
    {
        bitmapSource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(intPtr,
        IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally
    {
        DeleteObject(intPtr);
    }

    DeleteObject(intPtr);

    return bitmapSource;
}
```

This is ofcourse only the bitmap part - the actual loading is done the following way:

```
DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();

public MainWindow()
{

        this.Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        this.Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);

        this.Timer.Start();
}
void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WorldMap.Draw();
    map.Source = WorldMap.BitMapSource;
}
```

This is ofcourse only the important parts - i hope my question is understandable but just to clearify and repeat:

I need a WPF image to update 'every frame' or everytime specific values change.

My question might have been answered before, but i couldn't really find anything that work nor something suiting this instance.

BTW making the timer set off more frequently creates an error with the loading, but the exact error code, i can't remember, and i can't seem to create it again - never the less this probably isn't the most practical way of doing this.

EDIT:

For clarification, this is all i got right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQTmV.jpg
I want nothing fancy - it's just for personal projects playing around with programming and math, and that's alot easier if i can visualize the objects that i am 'moving' in my 2D plane.
Right now i am playing around with physics and gravity, trying to create a simple solar system with working physics. this is all just side projects to get to know the different tools better when i am too tired to work on my main project.

Comment: What does "update" mean in this context? reload an image or just switch between already loaded bitmaps for a visible image? What is the requirements for your application when updating images? What are acceptable framerates?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the image? I've suggested an alternative but would like to see if there is something about the image that can't be directly represents in wpf.

Comment: Why not just increase the Timer tick to a higher value?

Comment: @Default i have moving objects - they move 'constantly' which i'd like to have illustrated somehow within the WPF. I would like to have it update as often af the data updates. having it seem 'smooth' instead of laggy. My AI stuff runs on a while loop so that's not a constant speed.

Comment: @o_weisman This is the error i get, as i talked about " An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll 'there happened a gernic error in GDI+' "

Comment: @CDK There is no "frame". Windows also doesn't really work in resolutions of 1 milliseconds so your timer is of course pointlessly trying to work at that resolution. When I said increase the timer, I meant make it something like a 100 milliseconds TimeSpan which is about what the human eye is able to perceive anyway. This is a quick and not so great fix, but it should reduce the workload immensely. I see no reason for you to get an error because you increased the timer's tick interval, unless your code is misbehaving elsewhere.

Comment: if i make the interval 'smaler' it gives an error. making it update more rarely isn't really a solution as that is literally the opposite of what i want.

Other than that - i'm saying i need another method as this doesn't work.. if you then recommend the exact same way, that doesn't really help.. The problem, probably, is that if i make it activate too often then it will try updating before it finished updating the previous time, and as i can't anticipate that, this method ain't too great - which is the reason behind my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look to represent the visual elements of the bitmap as controls in WPF. That way you can update them directly and as frequently as they change, without the overhead of creating a bitmap and rendering it.

Performance would be far greater as you'd only update the changes in value.

To demonstrate the point, create a control...

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample_Chart.Views.CodeBehindChart"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         >
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" />
</UserControl>
```

This is as simple as they get. Next edit the code behind file...

```
public partial class CodeBehindChart : UserControl
{
    public CodeBehindChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Respond();
    }

    private async void Respond()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Random r = new Random();

        while (true)
        {
            this.LayoutRoot.Children.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, r.NextDouble() * this.LayoutRoot.ActualWidth);
                rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, r.NextDouble() * this.LayoutRoot.ActualHeight);

                rectangle.Width = 2;
                rectangle.Height = 2;
                rectangle.Fill = Brushes.Black;

                this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(rectangle);
            }

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code behind we have an async void method which firstly waits for 2 seconds (optional) before then creating 100 visual elements at random locations within the control. It refreshes this every 1/2 second.

If you did the same thing, but based those locations, sizes and fill - even use different shapes - I think you'll have a high performing, scaling and easily extendable solution to your requirements.

Taking this the next stage and controlling from a ViewModel will require a bit more thought which for your 'first project' - albeit an interesting one, may be a step ambitious ;)

Comment: not sure what you mean? having objects move on screen? like having a square image instead of a dot on the bitmap (for example)?

Not sure how this would be done as i have new objects enter the 'screen' and leave it - and no matter which way, i have to 'activate ' it somehow, and i have to do that in the mainthread.. which i can't figure out how to do repeatively, without some kind of timer ticker, which seams like a 'bad' way of doing it.

Comment: Should all be possible with view model and collections. You still need some governor to set the properties - that is where you can wrap that in a second interval timer. Just to me, redrawing a load of xaml elements, such as rectangle and ellipse, based on property values seems easier than generating bitmaps - plus it will scale, imagine running it on a 4K display. If you can post an image of the kind of thing you're trying, I might be able to give you a more concrete example to evaluate.

Comment: There isn't much to show.. i kinda am redoing my project, but it's just for personal use, so it's not really pretty.. but this is all the texturing i'm doing right now:
http://imgur.com/EIiSRFQ

I don't want anything looking fancy, i have no artistic skills so 'moving dots' is great enough for me. i'm just playing around with different stuff and trying to enhance my physics / math / programming skills all in one. But the dots should be moving as often as possible, but as i wrote to o_weisman, i get an error if i call my bitmap stuff every frame. but i'm kindof a noob to the whole WPF thing.

Comment: Edited OP, hoped it helped :)

Comment: That helps. I think this is very doable in wpf. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Works like a charm - but(!) how would i go around putting it in another class, as i can't access the canvas from other than the main-class..

Also - offtopic it's not my first project - i've been using C# for 2  -3 years ish. but haven't used WPF alot, so that's all pretty new to me :)

Comment: I did mean WPF, it is ambitious for first WPF - nothing wrong with that. You can create a dependency property on the control which takes input values for your visuals. Then bind these to a view model.

Comment: Thanks :) i'll look into the property control stuff!